# Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] Unable to locate the executable `mkdir` in React Native

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I'm using CocoaPods with Windows to build my React Native project with AppCenter.ms.
I should run `pod install` in ***ios*** folder. When it's ran, this error below is thrown:

```bash
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `GymTrackerAdmin`: RNCAsyncStorage, RNScreens, RNVectorIcons, appcenter-analytics, appcenter-core, appcenter-crashes, react-native-netinfo, and react-native-safe-area-context

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] Unable to locate the executable `mkdir`.

 #  from E:/Developing/GymApp/GymTrackerAdmin/ios/Podfile:13
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #    end
 >  end
 #  require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

I even removed spaces in folders name in the path above but nothing changed.

`pod --version: 1.12.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pod install` command only works on MacOS.